# How should I test meteor apps with package architecture?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I noticed that  [Vulan.js](https://github.com/VulcanJS/Vulcan) (one that implements package architecture) doesn't have tests. I tried to do it on my own, by adding [practicalmeteor:mocha](https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mocha) and adding `Package.onTest` to `package.js` that is in my package

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use([
    'myapp:package-that-i-wanna-test',
    'practicalmeteor:mocha',
    'practicalmeteor:chai'
  ])

  api.addFiles('somefile.test.js', 'server');
})
```

And then running `meteor test-packages --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha mypackage`

Is it a right solution?

I've also tried running  `meteor test --driver-package=practicalmeteor:mocha`, but got 0 tests even though I have them in my package named as `*.test.js` (so, it seems that this command does not look for test files in `packages` folder)

So, my question is what is the proper way of testing meteor app with `Vulcan.js` architecture and how should I perform running all tests in Vulcan.js